# Issue with the useForm hook. When I tried to access the registered field, I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lastName')"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm using the useForm hook from the react-hook-form (V7) library in my React component. However, I'm encountering the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sender')" when attempting to access the lastName field. I've tried the following solutions based on suggestions received:

Checked if the react-hook-form package is installed and imported correctly.
Verified that the register function is properly registering the lastName field.
Ensured that the input field associated with lastName has the correct name attribute.
Confirmed the dependencies (react, react-dom, react-hook-form) are installed and up to date.
Checked for conflicting dependencies and cleared cache when using a code bundler.
Despite trying these solutions, the error persists. Could someone please help me identify the cause of the error and provide guidance on resolving it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: The error message]

The components code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/SendMail.css';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

function SendMail() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    console.log(formData);
  };
  console.log('Registered Fields:', watch());
  return (
    <div className="sendMail">
      <div className="sendMail__header">
        <h3>New Message</h3>
        <CloseIcon className="sendMail__close" />
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          {...register('sender', { required: true })}
          type="text"
          placeholder="To"
        />
        {errors.sender && <p>Sender email is required</p>}

        <input
          name="subject"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Subject"
          {...register('subject', { required: true })}
        />

        {/* {errors.subject && <p>Subject is required</p>} */}
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Message..."
          className="sendMail__message"
          {...register('message', { required: true })}
        />
        {/* {errors.message && <p> message is required</p>} */}
        <div className="sendMail__options">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className="sendMail__send"
            type="submit"
          >
            Send
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SendMail;
```

Despite attempting to rewrite the code from scratch, I encountered the same error when using the useForm hook from the react-hook-form library. I consulted ChatGPT, which suggested that the code should be functioning correctly. Additionally, I thoroughly reviewed the available documentation for the library, but found no relevant information to address the error.

Comment: Well, you are using the API exactly as the docs recommends. I would debug this with a debugger and print statements. Also, for questions like this, posting the specific version installed from package.json is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change useForm hook like this

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors }   } = useForm();
```